# Rxjs ReplaySubject & pairwise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

Can we use `pairwise()` with `ReplaySubject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` with the first emitted value ?

With `BehaviorSubject` i can set the first value in the constructor so the `pairwise()` will work with the first `next()`. but here i need the replay behavior so any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Use `startWith` to add an initial value.

```ts
subject.pipe(
  startWith('first'),
  pairwise()
)
```